# Error: $ operator not defined for this S4 class using own data

Tags: r

I'm trying to replicate Robust Covariance Matrix Estimation for Mixed Models in in the link below with my own data:

https://strengejacke.github.io/sjPlot/articles/tab_model_robust.html

However, when I run:

```
# model parameters, cluster robust estimation for mixed models
tab_model(
  model, 
  vcov.fun = "CR", 
  vcov.type = "CR1", 
  vcov.args = list(cluster = iris$grp)
)
```

I get

```
Error: $ operator not defined for this S4 class
```

Does anyone know why this might be?

Comment: What does `isS4(iris)` say?

Comment: @danlooo it says False

Comment: So you may have a broken `model` object...

Comment: It might be an S3 object. Try with `iris@grp` instead.

Comment: I've tried iris@grp but it comes up with:                                                Error in do.call(clubSandwich::vcovCR, c(list(obj = x, type = vcov_type),  : 
  trying to get slot "cluster" from an object (class "data.frame") that is not an S4 object

Comment: @Sven iris is not overwritten by some S4 stuff, see my first question

Comment: @danlooo is there a way of fixing it? Could it be because it was originally a .sav file?

Comment: Hard to reproduce... Start redoing everything from a start R session (Click on session quit session in RStudio) and ensure that your global environemnt is empty at start

Comment: @danlooo still not working :(